# How to check if the value is integer in java?

Tags: java, integer

I'm using some API by restTemplate. The API returns a key whose type is integer.

But I'm not sure of that value, so I want to check whether the key is really an integer or not.
I think it might be a string.

What is the best way of checking if the value is really integer?

added:
I mean that some API might return value like below.
{id : 10} or {id : "10"}

Comment: Java is statically typed, so the API must have a fixed return type. I don't see what the point of this question is.

Comment: Is the return type actually `Integer` or is it a `string` representation of a number?

Comment: @NullUserException: The API might return an `Object` or something silly like that.

Comment: @ChrisParton That would be a silly way to do things.

Comment: what't the exact signature of the function?

Comment: @NullUserException: Yeah, hence the reason I said "silly" in my comment :) It would still be possible nonetheless. Maybe the API is a poorly-built socket wrapper? `ObjectInputStream`s return an Object when reading across a socket via `readObject()`. That's the only reason I could see an `Object` being returned.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Object x = someApi();

if (x instanceof Integer)
```

Note that if `someApi()` returns type `Integer` the only possibilities of something returned are:

- an `Integer`
- `null`

In which case you can:

```
if (x == null) {
    // not an Integer
} else {
    // yes an Integer
}
```

Comment: This fails for me in Java 7 when the string has other characters in it too.

Answer (score 11):

If what you receive is a String, you can try to parse it into an integer, if it fails, it's because it was not an integer after all. Something like this:

```
public static boolean isInteger(String str) {
    try {
        Integer.parseInt(str);
        return true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to use [Integer.valueOf(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: This assumes the object is a string. What if it's *actually* an Integer? This is where I don't understand the OP's question: they ask as if the return type is unknown (and unknowable)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your API return value can either be an Integer or String you can do something like this:

```
Integer getValue(Object valueFromAPI){
    return (valueFromAPI != null ? Integer.valueOf(valueFromAPI.toString()) : null); 
}
```